# To concatenate 4 images according to their name (in range of 4 from multiple images ) and store them in folder

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have four images of size 112*112 and I want to concatenate them into 1 image i.e 224*224.i tried using concatenate function but there are multiple images and from them i need only in a batch of 4 images.

Below is the code which contains four images "0607270001-1"... 01_01, 01_02,02_01,02_02 and concatenates them to be one image 0607270001-1. But i am having around 500 images in a folder and I want to group them in a pair of four based on the name.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('0607270001-1_01_01.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('0607270001-1_01_02.jpg')
vis1 = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
img3 = cv2.imread('0607270001-1_02_01.jpg')
img4 = cv2.imread('0607270001-1_02_02.jpg')
vis2 = np.concatenate((img3, img4), axis=1)
vis = np.concatenate((vis1, vis2), axis=0)
cv2.imwrite('0607270001-1.jpg', vis)
```

the images should be concatenated in this order:
01_01 01_02
02_01 02_02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to iterate through files in a directory. Your code would look like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import glob
import cv2

for img in glob.glob("*_01_01.jpg"):            # Iterate through all images ending with _01_01.jpg
    name = img.split('_')[0]                    # Extract the common part of group. Eg: 0607270001-1
    img1 = cv2.imread(name+'_01_01.jpg')    
    img2 = cv2.imread(name+'_01_02.jpg')
    vis1 = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
    img3 = cv2.imread(name+'_02_01.jpg')
    img4 = cv2.imread(name+'_02_02.jpg')
    vis2 = np.concatenate((img3, img4), axis=1)
    vis = np.concatenate((vis1, vis2), axis=0)
    cv2.imwrite(name+'.jpg', vis)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how to work with directories .... i have directory name 2007 with images name like                                                                                 
0707110001-1_01_01.jpg
0707110001-1_01_02.jpg
0707110001-1_02_01.jpg
0707110001-1_02_02.jpg
0707190001-1_01_01.jpg
0707190001-1_01_02.jpg
0707190001-1_02_01.jpg
0707190001-1_02_02.jpg
0709140001-1_01_01.jpg
0709140001-1_01_02.jpg
0709140001-1_02_01.jpg
0709140001-1_02_02.jpg

Comment: replace `glob.glob("*_01_01.jpg")` with `glob.glob("./2007/*_01_01.jpg")` and edit `name` accordingly.

Comment: And I want to group                                                                           
0707110001-1_01_01.jpg
0707110001-1_01_02.jpg
0707110001-1_02_01.jpg
0707110001-1_02_02.jpg
into one image name as 0707110001-1

Comment: I tried but its not working and it also doesn't shows any error

Comment: i am working with jupyter notebook so it works only once but I rerun the code again for other directories like 2008 it doesn't shows any combine image nor it shows an error

Comment: Thanks @VishnuDasu I got it ... I had some problems with jupyter notebook nothing else. Thank you very much you saved my time